# ComboBox Event works with ListBox but not with GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, combobox

```
The function should be simple:
I select an item, which is added to a list, then i manage that item using the list.

As first try i put some buttons next to the listbox and it worked fine.
But the objective is to add two buttons in each row, so i replaced the listbox with a gridview.

What's the problem? The event SelectedIndexChanged of the ComboBox (which is used to add the item to the list) does trigger once but not the second time.
The page correctly goes through page load, but the combobox's event is ignored.
```

Code here:
https://pastebin.com/Bmg2qjTf

```
I think i must say the combobox is filled using an SQL: the first time the SQL Query is executed and applied to the ComboBox's DataSource and in a Session, on PostBacks instead it gets refilled thru the Session variable.
```

Comment: Please don´t add code as images. Edit and add the code as formatted text to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really struggling with stackoverflow's code formatting method, i replaced everything with a pastebin. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Adding a txtNumSpedizione.Text = "";

Troubleshooting:
I tried to make both (listbox and gridview) work at the same time and this way it worked, also the gridview was getting all the selections.
So i figured out the difference between before and after was in the Text field "reset".